# What is the difference between leaf set and routing table entries in DHT?

Tags: dht

I am new to DHT (Distributed Hash Table). I have read theory regarding DHT (Pastry implementation - FreePastry). But I was really confused about distinction between *leaf set, routing table and neighborhood set*. What is their significance?
Also what is the difference between *keys and nodeIds* in the DHT ring? It would be really helpful if someone could provide an insight into it. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was able to find the following facts about DHT implementation of FreePastry:

1. Leaf Set- It is the no. of L closest nodes to a given node in the DHT ring. L/2 nodes are larger than the given nodeId and the rest L/2 is smaller than the given nodeId. The leaf set size 'L' is configurable in most of the cases.
2. Routing table - contains the information about the nodes connected to a given node to which it can send direct messages for routing. [For the process of routing, each node checks whether the address is present in its leaf set. If found then it delivers, else it routes the message to closest Id in the routing table.]
3. Neighbourhood set - It is deprecated as of now and I ahven't been able to find much info about it.

If someone has a better insight, plz share!